# Proof of $a - (b + c) = a - b - c$, Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-explanation

> Prove that a - (b + c) = a - b - c with the following axioms:
>
> “Associativity of +”: (a + b) + c = a + (b + c)
>
> “Associativity of ·”: (a · b) · c = a · (b · c)
>
> “Symmetry of +”: a + b = b + a
>
> “Symmetry of ·”: a · b = b · a
>
> “Additive identity” “Identity of +”: 0 + a = a
>
> “Multiplicative identity” “Identity of ·”: 1 · a = a
>
> “Distributivity of · over +”: a · (b + c) = a · b + a · c
>
> “Zero of ·”: a · 0 = 0
>
> “Unary minus”: a + (- a) = 0
>
> “Subtraction”: a - b = a + (- b)

So far what I did:

Proof:

```
a - (b + c)

a - (b + c) + 0 by Identity of +

a - (b + c) + (- (b + c) + (b + c)) by Unary minus
```

However, I can't get rid of the - sign in front of the - (b + c) what should I do?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Clarification for note:

We use an online system to enter our proofs and we start with either one side or
both sides.
Exm:
Proof:
     a - b - c
     then we do the next step under it
Exm: a + (- b) + (- c) Subtraction
     however we cannot start by one side and make up another equality

Exm: a - b + b -a = 0 - by unary minus is not allowed we cannot put equality
sign if we started with only one side.

When we start with one side the goal is to get the same exact thing on the other side.
Exm: in this case after the proofs steps I need to end up with
     a - (b + c)

Comment: While your clarifications on the online system you use are interesting, it is much more important for us to see the actual work you have done trying to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: You are right I was adding them. Sorry for posting the question without my steps.

Comment: Will the system accept turning -b into +(-1b)? Possibly with the use of multiplicative identity?

Comment: Unfortunately system does not accept the - b => + (- 1 * b) since it will require the axiom of - 1 * b = - b.

Comment: This question is exactly like a previous one of yours, but for a different identity. You should show us exactly what you were able to enter into your online system and where you are stuck.

Comment: Seems like this question indulges in an abuse of notation.  The right-hand side really ought to be $(a-b)-c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a-b)-c\overset{Identity \ of \ +}{=}$

$0+((a-b)-c)\overset{Unary \ Minus}{=}$

$((b+c)+(-(b+c)))+((a-b)-c)\overset{Symmetry \ of \ +}{=}$

$((a-b)-c)+((b+c)+(-(b+c)))\overset{Associativity \ of \ +}{=}$

$(((a-b)-c)+(b+c))+(-(b+c))\overset{Subtraction \ x \ 3}{=}$

$(((a+(-b))+(-c))+(b+c))-(b+c)\overset{Associativity \ of \ +}{=}$

$((a+(-b))+((-c)+(b+c)))-(b+c)\overset{Symmetry \ of \ +}{=}$

$((a+(-b))+((-c)+(c+b)))-(b+c)\overset{Associativity \ of \ +}{=}$

$((a+(-b))+(((-c)+c)+b))-(b+c)\overset{Symmetry \ of \ +}{=}$

$((a+(-b))+((c+(-c))+b))-(b+c)\overset{Unary \ Minus}{=}$

$((a+(-b))+(0+b))-(b+c)\overset{Identity \ of \ +}{=}$

$((a+(-b))+b)-(b+c)\overset{Symmetry \ of \ +}{=}$

$(b+(a+(-b)))-(b+c)\overset{Symmetry \ of \ +}{=}$

$(b+((-b)+a))-(b+c)\overset{Associativity \ of \ +}{=}$

$((b+(-b))+a)-(b+c)\overset{Unary \ Minus}{=}$

$(0+a)-(b+c)\overset{Identity \ of \ +}{=}$

$a-(b+c)$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just used some shortcuts as you sad because system allows to drop the parentheses and skip some symmetry laws as long as it follows the precedence of operators. Thank you again for writing a very detailed answer and explain everything very clearly and technically.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Start with $((a-b)-c) +(b+c)$.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prove that $x+y = 0\implies y=-x$ first.

Then I'd show that $(b+c) + (-b) + (-c) = 0$.

That'd mean that $-(b+c) = (-b) + (-c)$.

Then $a +(-(b+c)) = a+(-b) +(-c)$.

I trust you can fill in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Proof:

a - b - c start by right side

a - b - c + 0 by Identity of +

a - b - c + (- (b + c) + (b + c)) by Unary minus

a + - b + - c + - (b + c) + (b + c) by Subtraction

a + - b + - c + (b + c) + - (b + c) by Symmetry of +

(a + ((- b + b) + (- c + c))) + - (b + c) by Associativity of +

a + 0 + 0  + - (b + c)   by Unary minus

a + - (b + c) by Identity of +

a - (b + c)  by Subtraction

Comment: I hope it will be useful for others. I really appreciate everyone's help, however since our system work a bit different than usual mathematics this is the way that it is accepted.

Comment: You're taking a lot of short-cuts ... and dropping a lot of parentheses. Let me provide an Answer that's technically correct.